# SSRS dataset filter

Tags: reporting-services

Hi I'm trying to build a report in ssrs which gives the output based on current weekending date where end day is saturday. I'm pulling my data from SSAS Cube and I have a weekending date field so I applied a filter in the query designer to get the current weekending date using a parameter I used this expression:

`DateAdd("d",7-DatePart(DateInterval.Weekday,Today,FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday),Today)`

When I'm executing my query, it throws an error saying the restriction imposed by the constrained flag in the STRTOSET function were violated.

Please let me know how can I fix this.

Comment: i think you need to use that expression in dataset properties filters tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is thrown because you are passing a string that doesn't correspond with a valid member in your cube.

Note the Query Designer builds a MDX query based on the dimensions and members you select, this query uses the STRTOSET() function to convert your string parameter in a valid member.

```
...
STRTOSET(@CurrentWeekendDate,CONSTRAINED)
...
```

If you pass the current weekend date to your parameter it produces:

```
STRTOSET('2016-01-10',CONSTRAINED)
```

As `2016-01-10` is not a valid member in your Date dimension it throws the error.

You have to pass something like this depending on your cube:

```
[Date].[Date Key].&[2005-01-01T00:00:00]
```

So in SSRS you have to set your parameter to Text and use this expression:

**CORRECT EXPRESSION:**

```
="[200 Date].[Week Ending Date].&[" &
Format(
DateAdd("d",7-DatePart(DateInterval.Weekday,Today,FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday),Today),
"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss"
)
& "]"
```

**UPDATE:** If `[Week Ending date]` level doesn't include time:

```
="[Date].[Date Key].&[" &
Format(
DateAdd("d",7-DatePart(DateInterval.Weekday,Today,FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday),Today),
"yyyy-MM-dd"
)
& "]"
```

Go through [this tutorial](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3451/calendar-date-picker-for-mdx-based-sql-server-reporting-services-reports/) if you get stuck.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @sam, Does it throw the same error? If so show an example of valid member of your `200 Date` dimension.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help...I tried this expression as you have suggested "[200 Date].[Week Ending Date].&[" & format(DateAdd("d",7-DatePart(DateInterval.Weekday,Today,FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday), Today),"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss") &"]" and still it is throwing me the same error

Comment: @sam, navigate through `[200 Date].[Week Ending Date]` level in your cube in SSAS and select any date, right click it and select copy, then paste that here.

Comment: @zuleta 2016-10-01

Comment: @sam, I expected a valid member something like this: `[200 Date].[Week Ending Date].&[2016-10-01]`. If that is the case try the update in my answer.

Comment: then it is like this [200 Date].[Week Ending Date].&[2016-10-01T00:00:00]...I even tried the tutorial you provided and it is showing the same error

Comment: @sam, the error is thrown because the member you are passing is invalid. While I can't see the `[Week Ending Date]` members unique name I can't help you with the right SSRS expression.

Comment: @zuleta what do you mean by invalid member

Comment: @sam, your dataset query expects a member with the defined format in the level `[Week Ending Date]`.  If the level format is `[200 Date].[Week Ending Date].&[yyyy-mm-dd]` you have to pass `[200 Date].[Week Ending Date].&[2016-10-01]`. The error is thrown because you are passing an invalid member i.e the date in a different format.

Comment: @zuleta but my level format is [200 Date].[Week Ending Date].&[yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss] so I'm passing 200 Date].[Week Ending Date].&[2016-10-01T00:00:00] right so this is the correct format ryt

Comment: @sam, is your parameter `Text` type? Try setting it to `="[200 Date].[Week Ending Date].&[2016-10-01T00:00:00]"`. It should not throw the error.

Comment: @sam, I've updated my answer with the final expression. If your issue was solved you can select my answer as correct. [How to select an answer as correct?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @zuleta Hi i have one similar issue here I want to filter fiscal year week using a parameter and this doesnt have time so I used the following expression:  "[200 Date].[Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Yearweek].&[" & format(DateAdd("d",-DatePart(DateInterval.Weekday,Today,FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday), Today),"W/E MM/dd/yyyy") &"]"  the example of my valid member is W/E 02/05/11 I'm getting the same error as the above one please help me out

Comment: @sam. The issue you are explaining via comments is not related with the initial question in this thread. Post a new question specifying detailed information related to this new issue, it will get more visibility which helps your issue be solved.